# jquery mobile ajax post with multiple pages

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Im building an app with jQuery mobile and I have a little problem.

I've to pages:

index.html
test.html

On both pages I use an ajax post to get content from the database. When I test the app the results on index.html shows on the screen so that goes well but when I navigate to another page like test.html the results doesnt show. When I refresh the page test.html the results shows on the screen. Now when I go back to index.html the results are gone.

I tested on Chrome.

I hope somebody can tell me what the problem is.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile loads scripts **only from first page head** so you should put in your index head all the scripts (or scripts includes) also for the test.html page. You can even delete the head tags from the other pages.

Comment: I removed the scripts and the css from the page and put it on the index.html. This worked very well but the round corners and some other css styles on test.html dissapeared. The most styles are still the same but the round corners are gone. Any idea?

Comment: check if the styles you wrote override each other in some way, put both index and test styles in one single css document to be linked and carefully place the elements in the correct order so that they don't override one other's styles.

Comment: I tried that but that didnt work. One strange thing is that when I go to test.html the first time it worked, when I go back to index.html that worked also but when I go again to test.html the results are missing, very weird...

Comment: see if this is of any help http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html - this seems to say you should include every stylesheet and every script in every page.